# Spherical portal protection for objects

Tags: safety

So, I got an idea where I have this big object (A sphere, in my case) which I want to protect forever/as long as I can. I have spherical, two sided portals that last forever. These portals are like the ones in fireboy/watergirl, and each side can connect to a different portal. I can't have ANYTHING hitting my highly fragile object, so I'm putting this whole thing in space. The people trying to get to my object can break through any physical material, so the option of just covering up my object and sealing it in a hundred layers of graphene isn't an option. If only it were that simple. Assuming I have infinite spherical portals and these spherical portals are unbreakable and unmovable, what arrangement will protect my object for longest? Remember, the portals are SPHERICAL.

No pressure to get perfect logic, I'm not actually using this on a book. Just in my mind, for my own entertainment. I like logic A LOT.

Thanks!

EDIT:
The inside of one portal connects to the outside of another.

Comment: What do you mean by spherical? The portal is shaped like a hollow ball, and there is an inside and an outside of the portal?

Comment: Is the best answer two portals: one to put it into and one way the heck out in interstellar space for it to pop out of?

Comment: A description of the portals is important not everyone has seen the Movie? Book? whatever.

Comment: @Priska Yes. The object is probably going to be on the inside.

Comment: @CortAmmon I'm giving my robbers an infinite amount of time to steal my object, so assume they already know where my portals are.

Comment: Can you link an explanation of spherical portals?  I googled up fireboy and watergirl but did not find an explanation of how spherical portals work.  How does one access the interior of a spherical portal?

Comment: @Willk It's the same concept of fireboy and watergirl, except the portals aren't lines but spheres. To access the interior, you have to go to the portal's pair and go through the outside. In fireboy and watergirl, the characters are 2d (figured on a screen) and they are going through 1d (line) portals. In the game Portal, you're a 3d character (human) going through a 2d (circle on wall) portal. Here we have 4d characters going through 3d portals (spheres), but they are trying to defend against the tiny 3d thiefs.

Answer (score 1):

**Your 2 spherical portals are superimposed.**

Light or an object entering one side of the sphere will exit the other side of the sphere.  It will therefore be invisible.  In deep space it will also be untouchable.  I am not sure if gravity affects spherical portals.

Your sphere is in the center  of the 2 sphericslnportals.
Hopefully you can turn off the portals or you are not getting it back.

Comment: The spherical portals have two sides: the inside and the outside. That would work for flat portals, but not with these spherical portals. Sorry!

Comment: I guess I need more explanation of spherical portal mechanics.

Comment: That's why I needed to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

**Layers and opposites**

Consider at first just two portals, A and A' and the sphere, S. A and A' are on exact opposite sides of S. Assuming that orientation is preserved when entering a portal someone who enters A heading toward S will exit A' heading away from S.

Now just surround your sphere with a cube of portals. Worried about the space in between spheres? Just pack them like so (With two or three layers):

[image: Table salt]

Or if different sizes are impossible, like so:

[image: Metal atoms]

sphere seekers go in one side and come out the other.

Comment: The outside of one portal will connect to the inside of another. I think you're connecting the outside to the outside here...